# have QThread something like volatile member in Java?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have 5 QThread that are working together .
I have one integer variable that I want share it among them !
the work that one thread does on my integer is important for another thread .
how can share it between them ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QMutex` with a `QMutexLocker` around your variable.

EDIT:

```
QMutex * mutex = new QMutex();
int shared_integer = 0;

void func1()
{
    int temp;    
    // lots of calculations
    temp = final_value_from_calculations;

    // about to save to the shared integer
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(mutex);// this thread waits until the mutex is unlocked.
        qDebug() << "Mutex is now locked!";
        // access the shared variable
        shared_integer = temp;

        // if you had some reason to return early here, the mutex locker would
        // unlock your putex for you properly!
        // return; // locker's destructor gets called and the mutex gets unlocked

    }// lockers's destructor gets called and the mutex gets unlocked
    qDebug() << "Mutex is now unlocked!";

}

void func2()
{
    QMutexLocker locker(mutex);
    qDebug() << shared_integer;
}
```

Comment: @HamedNorouzi People are not going to write this for you, use the documentation!